# how to register new Members after deployment of ASP.net web Application without ASP.net configuration tool? Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, registration

I have used the installed ASP.net Web application template for my application and edited it as below.

I have made one web Application of ASP.net in visual studio 2012 and added 1 member and Admin in it also assign Roles to these two users and restricted access to some pages for anonymous users[also added one anonymous user with role assigned].

Now, I am going to deliver this to my firm which will eventually need some more membes to added and will assign role to them to access some members pages.

**Can after deployment of application Firm will able to add more Members to it?**

Registration in Web Application is working only for anonymous user. 
Can my firm will able to add new member through same?

Note: My firm dont have Visual studio installed so how can they be able to add new members after deployment of application? because there they will dont have access to ASP.net Configuration tool right?

Please help me solve this. Any Help will be appritiated.
Thank in advance!!

Comment: Your firm will be able to add more members if the credentials are given and the application has proper UI to do so, then fine. Better ask your firm what they actually want or want to deal.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. can you explain more about credentials?So firm will not have any access to ASp.net configuration tool without Visual Studio right? and making same registration made for anonymous users to uesrs having role as Members will  solve my query I think.

Comment: With credentials, I meant how does the users gets into the system like login, registration etc. Firstly if the system requires users to register first to access it, then it's fine. Noone will be able to get into it. Without visual studio, they can't configure anything actually. I guess, for roles, you have creared a table to assign them properly.

Comment: Yes, I have roles, membership and users tables in my database to store registered users with their assigned roles. Thanks again for explaination. Any other extra information will be accepted, as I am still not really clear about which way I should implement it.